# Error when Bundling my css using bundling js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bundling-and-minification

i am using bundling js for minimise my css file.but there was some error showing when i run the ection. the error showing is

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (11:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   i try some solution .but it is not working.. the problem isin my css file i have @fontface style. this is my webpack file

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
     csslib : [
     //  './stylesheets/layouts/bootstrap.min.css',

     ],
    css : [
      './stylesheets/layout.css',

    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './javascripts/dist/'),
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "file-loader",
          use:  [ 'css-loader' ,'style-loader'],
          publicPath : path.resolve(__dirname, './public/javascripts/dist/'),
        }),
      },
      {
        test:  /\.eot$|\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$|\.wav$|\.mp3$/, 
        loader: "file-loader" ,      
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('./stylesheets/dist/[name].css'),
  ]
}
```

and this is my layout css file

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'open_sansregular';
    src: url('../../fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../../fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Can any one please help me?

Comment: You’ll need to show us the file where the error is, where you’re loading the font face.

Comment: ya i am loading font face in layout css file

Comment: The error says it’s on line 11, and you’ve just posted it as if it were line 1. What’s on the other 10 lines?

Comment: ya others are normal css . i try with out that css but not working

Comment: What’s the file extension of the file? And so you’re saying that if you remove the `@font-face` from that file, it loads?

Comment: no i try css file having only @fontface {,..} .still it is not working

Comment: What’s the file extension of the file?

Comment: Try https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/355

Comment: it is a css file(layout.css)

Comment: @ThomasEdwards  i saw this link early but i did'nt understand what change need in my code

Comment: @ThomasEdwards any update?